# Why does geolocation stops working on Android Go after a deep clean?

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

The Cordova Geolocation plugin stops working on Android Go once the user does a deep clean on the device (clears all running apps).

I am building a Cordova app for Android that will be installed on multiple Blackview A20 mobile devices. The Blackview A20 devices runs a lite version of Android called Android Go. I am making use of the Cordova Geolocation plugin to track the device as the app is being used:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/

All works as expected and the longitude/latitude values gets sent to our server for saving. But as soon as a user press on the "Running/Active apps" soft button of the device and then press on the (X) button to close all running apps and clean the device memory and then run the app again, then the Geolocation plugin returns 0 for both longitude and latitude. The only way to fix this as far as I experienced is to restart the device itself, which is not a solution.

On the same device if you run the Google Maps Go app, the issue does not seem to occur as the Google Maps Go app still tracks the device as I move around. This could be due to the Google Maps Go app that might be a native Android app versus the hybrid Android app that I am building. Also the same app that I am building does not give the same issue on other devices (tested on a Blackview BV8000 Pro running Android 7.0 as well as a Samsung Galaxy S5 running Android 5.0). I tried button mapping apps to try prevent the users from pressing the Running/Active apps button but it still does not fix the issue at hand. I also tried multiple third party plugins to track Geolocation but same issue occurs.

I am not sure if this issue could be due to Android Go, Cordova Geolocation plugin or the Blackview A20 device. Any help appreciated.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onLocationFound, onLocationError, {"timeout":TIMEOUT_GEO_LOCATION});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly; when you make deep clean, you have to take permissions from user again or go app settings and check permissions panel and toggle location permission manually.

Comment: Does not seem to be the issue. I checked after the deep clean and the location permission for the app was still set to enabled. I tried to disable and enable the location permission again but still no luck.